# .NET 4.0 shared cache

Tags: .net, caching, shared

Is it possible to share a cache object between a ASP.NET and a WebService?

I have 3 Projects:

- ASP.NET WebSite
- WebService
- Class Library that contains the MyCache class

MyCache class:

...

```
Dim oCache As New MemoryCache("MyCache")
Dim oReturn as String

If oCache.Item("Key") Is Nothing Then
    oCache.Add("Key", "Value", Now.AddYears(1))
End If

oReturn = oCache.Item("Key")
```

...

This code is not working... when I call MyCache class in the WebSite, the "Key" is null (correct), but when I call the MyCache class in the WebService, the "Key" is null again (incorrect, it would be not null)

Comment: Take a look at AppFabric (Velocity). You are trying to cache across application domains and possibly web servers so you probably need a distributed caching solution. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windowsserver/ee695849.aspx

Comment: Is it possible to use a personal code instead of a third party solution?

Comment: @Fernando Yes, but why write something when it's already been written for you?

Comment: Also, have you looked at the [`System.Runtime.Caching` namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.aspx)?  If in the same application domain, then you can use the classes from the framework, otherwise, you have to use a solution like AppFabric (as mentioned by @Oppositional).

Comment: @Oppositional, I don't have full control on server to install such tool... I'll try to create the WebService inside the WebSite, like "www.website.com/webservice/service.asmx". I will tell you the result!

Answer (score 0):

I created the WebService inside the WebSite, like:

www.website.com/webservice/service.asmx